# Is there an extension that will install NPM in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code

Is there a Visual Studio Code extension that will install NPM itself? I can't remember but I think I had to install homebrew to get npm. I'd rather have it installed through an extension.

Note: I don't want extensions that will perform `npm install` but an install of `npm` itself.

**Background**
For example, if there is someone new to Visual Studio Code and new to NPM and I'd like to help them get their VSC environment setup with `npm`.